# Sitecore Rendering Datasource: Filter immediate children

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have a rendering and I want to restrict the items that are displayed in the datasource selection dialog UI. I want to restrict the datasource to the immediate children of the context item AND to a specific template. So I've set *Datasource Location* on the rendering to *./*. and specified the
*Datasource Template* to the required template.

The issue is, when i click to select a datasource, i see all immediate children including onces that are not of the template. Even though sitecore disables the "OK" button when i click other templates, its unnecessary noise. Additionally, I can even navigate to any of the descendants and select an item of that template. This wont work, as i want to restrict the selection to only the immediate children.

Any pointers?

FYI, im using sitecore 8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After some playing around i got it working by providing a query on the Datasource Location

I set it to: query:./*[@@templatename='x']